# How to collapse an array across a specific set of dimensions?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

In Matlab, we can collapse across dimensions of an array like this:

```
M     = rand(3,4,5);
myvec = M(:);        % gives a 60-element vector
```

I think it's called serialising or flattening. The order of the elements is dim1 first, then dim2, then dim3 --  so you get `[M(1,1,1); M(2,1,1); M(3,1,1); M(1,2,1); ...]`.

But what I want to do is collapse just along the first two dimensions:

```
mymatrix = M( :: , : ); % something that works like this?
```

to give a 12 x 5 matrix. So, for example, you get

```
[M(1,1,1)  M(1,1,2)  M(1,1,3)  M(1,1,4)  M(1,1,5)
 M(2,1,1)  M(2,1,2)  M(2,1,3)  M(2,1,4)  M(2,1,5)
 M(3,1,1)  M(3,1,2)  M(3,1,3)  M(3,1,4)  M(3,1,5)
 M(1,2,1)  M(1,2,2)  M(1,2,3)  M(1,2,4)  M(1,2,5)
 ...
]
```

So that the first dimension of `mymatrix` is the "flattened"  1st and 2nd dimensions of the original `M`, but preserving any other dimensions.

I actually need to do this for the "middle 3 dimensions" of a 5-dimensional array, so a general solution would be great! e.g. `W=rand(N,N,N,N,N); mymatrix = W( :, :::, : )` should give a `N x N^3 x N` matrix if you see what I mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) with square brackets (`[]`) as a placeholder for one of the dimension length arguments:

```
sz = size( M );
mymatrix = reshape( M, [], sz(end) );        % # Collapse first two dimensions
```

or

```
mymatrix = reshape( M, sz(1), [], sz(end) ); % # Collapse middle dimensions
```

The placeholder `[]` tells `reshape` to calculate the size automatically. Note that you can use only one one occurrence of `[]`. All other dimension lengths must be specified explicitly.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Should have thought about reshape. PS I just thought of another way that appears to work: `tmp = permute(M, [1,5,2,3,4]);`, `mymatrix=tmp(:,:)`. Not sure if it will always work? Of course `reshape` is **much** preferable.